# iOS MultiTouch Event in different uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have two different UIView on the UIViewcontroller.

That UIView are left UIView (leftScreenView) and right UIView(rightScreenView).

They are differentiate subview leftJoystickView(on leftScreenView) and rightJoystickView(on rightScreenView).

But I found problem about below:

When I touch on the leftScreenView and moving, now I touch other finger on the rightScreenView.

Now the touch event always become on the leftScreenView. That can't to differentiate between leftScreenView and rightScreenView event.

I need touch on the leftScreenView and moving and touch on the rightScreenView moving are different event (do moving) at the same time.

**How can I process multi touch distinguishing different moving event and began event?**

```
 #pragma mark ----- touch action -----
 -(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
 //    NSLog(@"------touchesBegan-------");
     UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

     CGPoint touchViewPoint = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

     CGPoint  touchLeftScreenPoint = [touch.view convertPoint:touchViewPoint toView:self.leftScreenView];
     CGPoint  touchRightScreenPoint = [touch.view convertPoint:touchViewPoint toView:self.rightScreenView];

     NSLog(@"touch left:%d",[self.leftScreenView pointInside:touchLeftScreenPoint withEvent:event]);
      NSLog(@"touch right:%d",[self.rightScreenView pointInside:touchRightScreenPoint withEvent:event]);

     NSLog(@"touch.tapCount:%ld", touch.tapCount);

     if( [self.leftScreenView pointInside:touchLeftScreenPoint withEvent:event] )
     {
         NSLog(@"began click left screen");

         self.leftStickLfConstraint.constant = touchLeftScreenPoint.x ;
         self.leftStickTopStickConstraint.constant = touchLeftScreenPoint.y ;


         [self.leftJoystickView touchesBegan:touches   withEvent:event];
     }else if( [self.rightScreenView pointInside:touchRightScreenPoint withEvent:event] )
     {

         NSLog(@"began click right screen");

         self.rightStickLfConstraint.constant = touchRightScreenPoint.x ;
         self.rightStickTopConstraint.constant = touchRightScreenPoint.y ;
         [self.rightJoystickView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

     }


     NSLog(@"  ");
 }
```

The move event is below:

```
 -(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
     UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
     CGPoint touchViewPoint = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

     NSLog(@"moved touch.tapCount:%ld", touch.tapCount);
     NSLog(@"moved touches count:%ld", [touches count]);

     CGPoint  touchLeftScreenPoint = [touch.view convertPoint:touchViewPoint toView:self.leftScreenView];
     CGPoint  touchRightScreenPoint = [touch.view convertPoint:touchViewPoint toView:self.rightScreenView];

     if( [self.leftScreenView pointInside:touchLeftScreenPoint withEvent:event] )
{
         NSLog(@"touchesMoved click left screen");

         [self.leftJoystickView touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

     }else if( [self.rightScreenView pointInside:touchRightScreenPoint withEvent:event] )
     {
         NSLog(@"touchesMoved click right screen");

        [self.rightJoystickView touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
     }

 }
```

When I keep on the leftScreenView at moving, then touch rightScreenView.

I always get touch left:1 touch right:0.

Log:

```
 2015-05-08 14:20:30.946 DroneG2[3606:942222] touchesMoved click left screen
 2015-05-08 14:20:30.947 DroneG2[3606:942222] touches count:1
 2015-05-08 14:20:30.962 DroneG2[3606:942222] moved touch.tapCount:1
 2015-05-08 14:20:30.962 DroneG2[3606:942222] moved touches count:1
 2015-05-08 14:20:30.962 DroneG2[3606:942222] touchesMoved click left screen
 2015-05-08 14:20:30.963 DroneG2[3606:942222] touches count:1
 2015-05-08 14:20:30.982 DroneG2[3606:942222] moved touch.tapCount:1
 2015-05-08 14:20:30.982 DroneG2[3606:942222] moved touches count:1
 2015-05-08 14:20:30.983 DroneG2[3606:942222] touchesMoved click left screen
 2015-05-08 14:20:30.983 DroneG2[3606:942222] touches count:1
 2015-05-08 14:20:30.984 DroneG2[3606:942222] touch left:1
 2015-05-08 14:20:30.985 DroneG2[3606:942222] touch right:0
```

How can i process multi touch on different uiview?

I had add below in viewdidload:

```
 self.leftScreenView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
 self.rightScreenView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
 //    self.leftScreenView.exclusiveTouch = NO;
 //    self.rightScreenView.exclusiveTouch = NO;

self.view.multipleTouchEnabled =  YES;
```

my storyboard screenshot :

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to distinguish between begin and end, why didn't you use a `UIGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: Because on the began , moving and end have different action in the joystick. So I using the touchbegan. If use the UIGestureRecognizer how to distinguish the touchbegan on the different view? thank you.

Comment: You can check the `UIGestureRecognizer`'s state.

Comment: excuse me, If using UIGestureRecognizer, Is addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture  add to self.view or self.leftScreenView and self.rightScreenView? thanks.

Comment: You add it to the specific view. So: `self.view.addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture` or `self.leftScreenView.addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture`

Comment: If I want to process leftscrrenview and rightscreenview, not at leftScreenView have multi touch, it's one finger on the left, other finger on the right. So I need add two gestureRecognizer self.leftScreenView.addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture and self.rightScreenView.addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture both? And I see the Recognizer status, have not touch move delegate method can use,@@. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `UIGestureRecognizer` to each of your views inside `-viewDidLoad`. With a `UIGestureRecognizer` you are able to track the state of the gesture. As an example you can use the following.

```
//Add a gesture recognizer to each view
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = 
[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self                                                                   
                                        action: @selector(handlePan:)];
panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
[self.myView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

Now inside of `-handlePan` you can track the state and view that contains the gesture.

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture{

    UIView *view = gesture.view; //View that contains gesture

    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){

    }else if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){

    }else if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){

    }

}
```

---

**Edit:**

To distinguish between the left and the right view you can add a `tag` to each view.

```
leftView.tag = 0;
rightView.tag = 1;
```

Then inside of `-handlePan:`

```
UIView *view = gesture.view; //View that contains gesture

if(view.tag == 0)
   //...

if(view.tag == 1)
   //...
```

---

**Edit2:**

You need to add the gesture to the left and right view, not the view of the view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.leftScreenView.tag = 0;
    self.rightScreenView.tag = 1;


    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture =
    [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action: @selector(handlePan:)];
    panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    [self.leftScreenView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture1 =
    [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action: @selector(handlePan:)];
    panGesture1.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    [self.rightScreenView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture1];

}
```

Comment: If using UIPanGestureRecognizer, how to distinguish between leftScreenView and right ScrrenView should call [self.leftJoystickView touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];  , please. thank you

Comment: Sorry, I try your code, If I drag on the tag=0(leftVIew), not touch up(end) situation . then click right view, there are not show log tag=1(right view).@@

Comment: First, thanks. If I want to take touch began and touch end event, I should UITapGestureRecognizer right? UIPanGestureRecognizer just for move situation.

Comment: @dickfala Yes, refer to the documentation here - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html and please accept my answer)

Comment: wait me resolve my question and using your answer apply my application. I will accept your answer. thank you at the first.

Comment: I found using method have some question, I had call [self.rightJoystickView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; there are not have touches variable...Orz

Comment: In the rightJoystickView, there have touchbegan touchmove and touchend should be called. :(

Comment: Then, I use touchbegan to implement. But I have encounter touchmoved delay problem in here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30181332/how-to-resolve-touchesmoved-lag-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this situation using `- touchesForView:` of `UIEvent`. `- touchesForView:` returns the `UITouch` set. Check if the returned set contains the leftSideView or RightSideView, if yes then handle the move event. Following is the code snippet:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

// get the touch set of leftside view
NSSet *eventTouches1 =  [event touchesForView:leftSideView];

// get the touch set of rightside view
NSSet *eventTouches2 =  [event touchesForView:rightSideView];

// check if the eventTouches1 is not null
if (eventTouches1) {
    UITouch *touch1 = [[eventTouches1 allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([touch1.view isEqual:leftSideView]) {

        // handle drag event for left side view
    }
}

// check if the eventTouches2 is not null
if (eventTouches2) {
    UITouch *touch2 = [[eventTouches2 allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([touch2.view isEqual:rightSideView]) {

        // handle drag event for right side view

    }
}
```

}

This can also be achieved by using `UIGestureRecognizer` also.