# ios not get other finger (multitouch) event in UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How can I get multitouch and single touch  event?

I try to touch moving (not touch up) using left finger, now I click right finger on the screen, But I try to get right finger touch event or touch point(this time the left finger still moving on the screen).

I set the log [gesture numberOfTouches] or [gesture numberOfTouchesRequired]. I still get 1, not get 2.

In my ViewDidLoad method I set below code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
 self.view.multipleTouchEnabled =  YES;
 self.view.exclusiveTouch = NO;

 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *panelLongPressGestureRecognizer =
 [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panelLongPressRecgonizerAction:)];
 panelLongPressGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;

//panelLongPressGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
//panelLongPressGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
panelLongPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.001;
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:panelLongPressGestureRecognizer];


 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *panelLongDoublePressGestureRecognizer =
 [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panelLongPressRecgonizerAction:)];
 panelLongDoublePressGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
 panelLongDoublePressGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
 panelLongDoublePressGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
 panelLongDoublePressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.001;
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:panelLongDoublePressGestureRecognizer];
 }

 - (void)panelLongPressRecgonizerAction:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer
 {
 switch (gestureRecognizer.state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        NSLog(@" === long press began ===");
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        NSLog(@" === long press changed ===");
        [self pressChanged:gestureRecognizer];
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        NSLog(@" === long press end ===");
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        NSLog(@" === long press cancell ===");
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
        NSLog(@" === long press failed ===");
        break;


}
NSLog(@" ");
```

}

```
- (void) pressChanged:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *) gesture
{
    NSLog(@"moved guesture.number of touches:%ld", [gesture numberOfTouches]);
    NSLog(@"moved numberOfTouchesRequired of touches:%ld", [gesture numberOfTouchesRequired]);

}
```

I still get log:

```
 2015-05-11 14:25:46.117 DroneG2[7521:1149008]  === long press changed ===
 2015-05-11 14:25:46.118 DroneG2[7521:1149008] moved guesture.number of touches:1
 2015-05-11 14:25:46.118 DroneG2[7521:1149008] moved numberOfTouchesRequired of touches:1
```

Have anyone know where is my question in my code?

I want to get other finger touch point or event  when I moving?

Or have other method can achieve to get multitouch coordinate sequence ?

thank you very much.

Comment: Make sure you tap twice to get event for panelLongDoublePressGestureRecognizer.

Comment: I don't know why , When I moving a finger on the screen, then other finger click on the screen, that not enter panelLongDoublePressGestureRecognizer. Do you know why?

Comment: The user must press one or more fingers on a view and hold them there for a minimum period of time before the action triggers. While down, the user’s fingers may not move more than a specified distance; if they move beyond the specified distance, the gesture fails. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html

Comment: So If I want to touch moving one finger, then click other finger.What method can get other finger touch down method in touch moving?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For complex touch events use 
Method of UIResponder..

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

to calculate and differentiate touch events.

[Apple Doc for multitouch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW9)

Comment: My problem is extend from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117145/ios-multitouch-event-in-different-uiview/30117970?noredirect=1#comment48371038_30117970. I am using touchesBegan orininal.

Comment: When I used the touchedMoved, It will delay. You can see my question in here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30181332/how-to-resolve-touchesmoved-lag-in-ios